# 2nd line text off to other side (CSS)

Tags: css, forms

[image]

In the above image I have a field on my form. I would like the text to sit within the area highlighted in red.

I have currently set the following in the CSS for the field.

```
.checkbox-text{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: is checkbox-text used as span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `width` and `height` only work when the element is in block mode, not inline, which is the default for most text elements.

But you still need it to be inline as well, so that it keeps to its current position in the page flow.

Therefore you need inline-block mode. You can add this to your stylesheet like this:

```
.checkbox-text{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Now your `height` and `width` properties will work.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the element with the class `checkbox-text` is an inline elements, to which `width`doesn't apply. Add `display: block`.

And next time, please, show your HTML.